# Is there any way to logout from a page without using auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to logout from a page and redirect to signin page without using auth as shown below.

> **Auth::logout();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the session's [regenerate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#regenerating-the-session-id) or [flush](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#deleting-data) to purge all of the session:

```
request()->session()->regenerate(true);
request()->session()->flush();

// then redirect to login
return redirect()->route('login');
```

**update**

You have two return statements in your comment's code:

```
public function signout(Request $request) {
    // don't return here
    // return Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/login'); 
}
```

Comment: Find my controller code:

public function signout(Request $request) {
        return Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
      }

Comment: Ok just replace `Auth::logout` with `request()->session()->regenerate(true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::flush();
return redirect()->route('login');
```

//use session in your controller